# Is it required to open LDAP port?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ldap

Is it required to open LDAP port. if active directory installed in that server.how LDAP communicate with access management with the help of LDAP.

Comment: are you encountering a specific error message?

Comment: No .I'm not getting any errors messages.My doubt is how it will work without port in open state.please provide my the answer to my question asap.

Comment: If the servers are in same LAN it's not required to open LDAP server port to global